# El siguiente código es erróneo no corre la función ELSE

Tags: python, funciones, terminal, else

me gustaría saber la razón por la cual no corre la función ELSE aun poniendo una respuesta diferente a "Tú" or "tu".

```
respuesta = input("Espejito, espejito, ¿quién es la más bella del reino?: ")

if respuesta == "Tú" or "tú":
    print("Lo sabía...")
else:
    print("COMO!!!")
```

Comment: `else` no es una función sino una sentencia. Aparte de eso, lo que querías escribir era `if respuesta == "Tú" or respuesta == "tú"`. Lo que has escrito hace una cosa diferente. Puedes abreviar usando una lista de opciones y mirando si la respuesta está en la lista: `if respuesta in ["Tú", "tú", "Tu", "tu"]` por ejemplo, o incluso `if respuesta.lower() in ["tú", "tu"]` para no tener que meter las variaciones de mayuscula/minúscula (en este caso admitiría incluso "TU" o "tU")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separa la condición, ya que no la estás valorando bien. También es aconsejable emplear siempre paréntesis para saber el orden que estás aplicando en la comparación.
El código correcto sería:

```
respuesta = input("Espejito, espejito, ¿quién es la más bella del reino?: ")

if ( (respuesta == "Tú") or (respuesta == "tú") ):
    print("Lo sabía...")
else:
    print("COMO!!!")
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 4):

El error está en el `if`:

```
if respuesta == "Tú" or "tú":
```

Aquí hay dos expresiones lógicas unidas por un `or`:

- `respuesta == "Tú"`
- `"tú"`

La primera expresión compara la respuesta contra "Tú", lo que puede ser `True` o `False`.

La segunda expresión, `"tú"` es siempre cierta, pues en Python un string no vacio siempre es `True`.

Como haces un `or`, el `if` siempre se cumple.

#### Solución

Escribir apropiadamente el `if`:

```
respuesta = input("Espejito, espejito, ¿quién es la más bella del reino?: ")

if respuesta == "Tú" or respuesta == "tú":
    print("Lo sabía...")
else:
    print("COMO!!!")
```

produce:

```
Espejito, espejito, ¿quién es la más bella del reino?: María
COMO!!!

Process finished with exit code 0
```

también:

```
Espejito, espejito, ¿quién es la más bella del reino?: tú
Lo sabía...

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Alternativas

En lugar de múltiples comparaciones individuales, puedes simplemente preguntar si la respuesta está en una lista de alternativas:

```
if respuesta in ["Tú", "tú"]:
```

Es útil cuando las alternativas son dos o más.

También se usa transformar la respuesta a minúsculas (o mayúsculas) para reducir el número de comparaciones:

```
if respuesta.lower() in ["tú", "tu"]:
```

con lo que cubrimos todas las posibles variaciones minúsculas/mayúsculas, acentos/sin acentos: `tu, Tu, TU, tU, tú, Tú, TÚ, tÚ`

Answer (score 0):

Añadir a las opciones dadas por @CandidMoe una más que tenemos disponible a partir de Python3.10 (cuya versión oficial acaba de aparecer hace unas semanas).

Se trata del [*structural pattern matching*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0636/). Esta nueva sintaxis es muy potente y permite muchísimas más cosas, pero para el caso particular de comparar una cadena con varias opciones podría usarse por ejemplo así:

```py
seguir = True
while seguir:
    respuesta = input("Quieres seguir? ")
    match respuesta.lower():
        case "si" | "yes" | "ok":  # Observa el uso de | para dar las diferentes opciones
            print("Has dicho que si")
        case "no":
            print("Vale, adiós")
            seguir = False
        case _:  # Este es el caso en que encaja todo lo demás
            print("Respuesta no válida")
```